# Bounding the error of a quadratic form based on distance between two quadratic form matrices

Tags: variance, covariance-matrix, matrix, quadratic-form

In survey statistics, it is common to estimate sampling variance for a sum using a quadratic form. For example, I want to estimate the number of people in the U.S. who have been diagnosed with a certain disease: my estimate is a sum of observations in my sample.

$$\hat{Y} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i$$

To estimate the sampling variance, I use a variance estimator which can be represented as a positive definite quadratic form, based on the $n$-vector of observations, $\mathbf{y}$, and an $n \times n$ matrix, $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$:

$$v(\hat{Y}) = \mathbf{y}^{\prime} \boldsymbol{\Sigma} \mathbf{y}$$

In practice, it is common to approximate $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$, using a method such as bootstrapping or the jackknife, so that we instead estimate our variance as follows:

$$v_{Q}(\hat{Y}) = \mathbf{y}^{\prime} \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{y}$$

Suppose we can control the distance between $\mathbf{Q}$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$: specifically, we can reduce the squared Frobenius norm $\lVert\mathbf{Q} - \boldsymbol{\Sigma}\rVert_F^2$ or the squared Euclidean norm $\lVert\mathbf{Q} - \boldsymbol{\Sigma}\rVert_2^2$ to some arbitrary, nonzero value. I would like to be able to put a bound on the difference between the two quadratic forms, as a function of the distance between $\lVert\mathbf{Q} - \boldsymbol{\Sigma}\rVert_F^2$ and, if necessary, some other quantity such as $\hat{Y}$. Ideally, I would like to be able to make a statement about the relative error of using $\mathbf{Q}$ instead of $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$. For example, I would like to make a statement such as $$\lVert\mathbf{Q} - \boldsymbol{\Sigma}\rVert_F^2 < 0.01 \implies \frac{\|v_{Q}(\hat{Y}) - v(\hat{Y})\|}{v(\hat{Y})} < 0.01$$ or $$\lVert\mathbf{Q} - \boldsymbol{\Sigma}\rVert_F^2 < 0.01 \implies \frac{\|v_{Q}(\hat{Y}) - v(\hat{Y})\|}{\hat{Y}^2} < 0.01$$ The first bound is relative in the sense of expressing the "percent error" of the variance estimate, while the second bound is relative in the sense that it bounds the error of the estimated coefficient of variation for $\hat{Y}$, defined as $\frac{\sqrt{v(\hat{Y})}}{|\hat{Y}|}$. Either kind of bound would be useful to have.

**What bounds on the relative error of using $\mathbf{Q}$ instead of $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ can I make, given the squared Frobenius norm $\lVert\mathbf{Q} - \boldsymbol{\Sigma}\rVert_F^2$ or the squared Euclidean norm $\lVert\mathbf{Q} - \boldsymbol{\Sigma}\rVert_2^2$?**